# Pointer to a non-static data members incorrect in VS2015 Update 2

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

There seems to be a regression in C++ compiler in VS2015 Update 2 - incorrect addess of a base class data member is calculated when using multiple inheritance with one of the classes having a virtual destructor. Code example:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

struct V
{
    virtual ~V() {};
};
struct B
{
    int i;
};
struct A : public B, public V
{
};
int main()
{
    int A::* a1 = &A::i;
    A a;

    a.i = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    if (a.*a1 == std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
        std::cout << "ok\n";
    else
        std::cout << "nok\n";
}
```

It looks like *a1* gets the offset to v-table instead of *i*.

This code used to print *ok* in VS2015 until update 1 and *nok* in update 2. My checks in GCC and Clang printed also *ok*.

Are there any limitations on multiple inheritance when working with pointers to members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, in case some one having the same issue: there is indeed a [regression](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2555433) in Update 2, as also discussed [on MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/15529acd-259b-488d-8961-13e834cdc1fe/c-pointer-to-member-nullptr-check-fails-with-multiple-inheritance?forum=vclanguage). Basically you have two options:

1. Use `/vmg`compiler switch (This will increase the size of your binary).
2. Get correct offset via base class `&B::i` and assign it to the derived class `A`